# Limites Binance API Websocket

Tags: python, websocket, binance

Tengo una pregunta relacionada con los limites impuestos en la API de Binance para los websocket.

Esta consiste en que tal y como vemos en la siguiente imagen, según la información oficial de la API se pueden acceder a Streams de datos a partir de una url, en la que teóricamente podemos suscribirnos hasta un total de 200 streams.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi problema viene en la parte en la que especifica que la conexión tiene un límite de 10 mensajes de entrada, y es que con suscribirme a 8 streams de datos ya llegan más de esa cantidad de mensajes cada segundo.

Por lo que me mis preguntas serian las siguientes:

1. ¿Existe alguna forma de limitar la cantidad de mensajes a 10 por segundo utilizando la librería websocket de python?
2. ¿Estoy entendiendo bien los limites, o con mensajes de entrada se refiere a los que yo envió al servidor y no los que el me envía?

Finalmente os adjunto un pequeño fragmento de código el cual se conecta a 7 streams de datos diferentes y muestra por pantalla cuando recibe un dato correspodiente al primero de una nueva vela de un minuto.

```
import websocket
import json
import pprint
from datetime import datetime
import time

SOCKET = "wss://fstream.binance.com/stream?streams=bnbusdt@kline_1m/trxusdt@kline_1m/atomusdt@kline_1m/ethusdt@kline_1m/adausdt@kline_1m/btcusdt@kline_1m/xrpusdt@kline_1m"
numero = 0

def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)
  
def on_open(ws):
    print('open connection')

def on_close(ws):
    print('close connection')

def on_message(ws, message): 
    
    ws.numero +=1
    json_message = json.loads(message)
    json_message=json_message['data']
    candle = json_message['k']
    is_candle_closed = candle['x']
        
    if is_candle_closed:
        print(ws.numero)
        print(time.time()-ws.time)
       

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(SOCKET, on_open=on_open, on_close=on_close, on_error=on_error, on_message=on_message)
ws.numero = 0
ws.time = time.time()
ws.run_forever()
```

Simplemente con esos streams y dejandolo funcionar un par de minutos recibo 2031 mensajes en 149 segundos, lo cual esta por encima del limite soportado.

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda y atención.

Answer (score 0):

La solucion es sencilla, puedes abrir multiples websockets y suscribirte a distintas cosas, yo he llegado a tener 150 websockets abiertos (200 es el maximo) sin problemas. Yo al menos lo entiendo así, no tendria sentido que te puedas suscribir a 20 en un mismo websocket y luego poner un limite de 10 por segundo.

Te indica que no puedes recibir mas de 10 mensajes por segundo en un mismo websocket, así lo cumples sobradamente.

Mezclando ambas limitaciones y sin el uso de otras alternativas como proxys puedes tener un total de 2000 mensajes / segundo.

Aun así algunos mensajes se actualizan con una frecuencia de 250ms como la suscripcion a una moneda. aunque luego en la practica es falso, porque no envian más de 3 mensajes por segundo. Con esto quiero decir que si administras correctamente las suscripciones (yo en un canal de 250ms de actualizacion meteria 3 monedas) no deberias tener problemas con los limites.

Otra opcion es como he comentado el uso de un proxy o incluso dependiendo de como estes haciendo el cliente que se conecta distribuirlo entre varias maquinas/ips.